# Increase Bulk load

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis, bulk-insert, query-performance

We have a SSIS package which do bulk insert in batch. But from couple of days the duration of the job which runs the package has been increased. Its running for 4-5 hours which usually used to get executed in 30-40 Min.
Almost 50 Million records are getting inserted, which is taking more time.
MOst of the time query getting into suspended mode with wait_type PAGEIOLATCH_EX.
Any suggestion to improve the performance of this bulk insert ?

Comment: How many records are typically loaded? What is the commit size and rows per batch setting? Is the source data ordered?

Comment: Check out [Speeding Up SSIS Bulk Inserts into SQL Server](http://henkvandervalk.com/speeding-up-ssis-bulk-inserts-into-sql-server), by Henk van der Valk, for optimizations you can use with the Bulk Insert Task and review [Guidelines for Optimizing Bulk Import](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177445(v=sql.105).aspx), by MS, for optimizations you can make at the database level.

Comment: Is it VM?  Did you monitor your disks?